# Unity 2d square position not lining up with its size

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, coordinates

I want to have one square that rests at the Unity 2d coordinates (5,5). Using `transform.localScale` I make the square be 3 units by 3 units large. So I thought that if I made another square that is the exact same except it is at the coordinate (8,5), the second square would be directly to the right of the first one, touching it. But instead, the square spawns a bit more to the right than it should, implying that the size x,y units are smaller than the position x,y units. Any way I can solve this problem, and have both touching? Thank you.

Code for placing the squares (tileHeight = 3 and tileWidth = 3):

```
GrassTile.transform.localScale = new Vector3(tileWidth, tileHeight, 0f);
Instantiate (GrassTile, new Vector3 (0f, 15f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
Instantiate (GrassTile, new Vector3 (3f, 15f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
```

Screenshot of what it looks like, as well as what the prefab looks like:
[image: Unity inspector of what game looks like.]

Screen shot of the grassTile stats:
[image]

Comment: What are you using for your square? If it's a quad with unit width it should line up exactly, but if the native size of your object is smaller than one unit then you'll see a gap (since `3*[something less than 1] = [something less than 3]` )

Comment: @DMGregory I am using a prefab. I do not know it's native size, I just used transform.localscale.

Comment: OK I will add a screenshot a soon as I can!

Comment: @DMGregory K I uploaded the screenshot!

Comment: @DMGregory It says next to scale: x: 3 y: 3 z: 0

Comment: @DMGregory I just right clicked in the hierarchy, and selected new game object. I clicked and dragged a green, square grass sprite from my sprites folder and dragged it into the object, renamed it to grass Tile, and dragged it into the prefabs folder. To access it, I use `public GameObject GrassTile;` In the code, then in the inspector I set the grassTile GameObject to the grassTile prefab. And to resize and palce it, I use the code displayed in my question.

Comment: So the answer to my very first question is "It's a Sprite" — that would've saved us four hours. This is the kind of information that should be in a question from the start to make problems easier to diagnose. Next questions: what is the resolution of your grass texture and what is the Pixels Per Unit value it's been imported with? (Find this by clicking on the texture in your Project window)

Comment: @DMGregory It has 100 pixels per unit.

Comment: That's one of the two things I asked for. The other is the width & height of the texture itself in pixels. I'm not going to continue repeating myself, so please read more carefully.

Comment: @DMGregory It is 64X64 pixels large. Sorry for the weird answers I am giving. I am new to unity. d=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is 64x64 and your Pixels To Units setting is 100.

That means at native size your Sprite is 64/100 = 0.64 units wide.

To make this 3 units wide, you'd need to set your local scale to 3/0.64 = 4.6875

Or, you can change your Pixels to Units setting to 64, then your sprite will come in at exactly 1x1 unit, and a local scale of 3 will make it 3 units wide, as you originally expected.

Comment: Thnak you so much, man! =D